# How to validate for length of an integer in Json Schema?

Tags: json, regex, validation, jsonschema

Simulator: https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/L3FmJnoE

It looks like json schema validation does not check for regex patterns for integers.
How to validate for length of an integer?

Json Schema -

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",

  "title": "title",
  "type": "object",
  
  "properties": {
    "amount": {
      "type": "integer",
        "example": 199,
          "maxLength": 1,
            "pattern": "^[0-9]{1}$"
    }
  }

}
```

My Json which should fail validation but does not -

```
{
  
 "amount": 343434343434343434334343434343434
 
 }
```

Comment: Note that `^[0-9]{1}$` = `^[0-9]$`. `{1}` is always redundant. Are you sure you can apply a regex check to an int?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `maximum` ([specification](https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.2.2)) keyword and the related ones to set a maximum value for numbers. Regular expressions are only applied to string values ([more details here](https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-validation.html#pattern)).

(`maxLength` is also only applied to string values)